# MYSQLi search and replace with a quoted font name

Tags: mysql, search, replace, quotes

When building my web site I initially used the font Verdana quite a bit.  I now wish to go through the mysql database and change all instances of :

font-family: Verdana;

to

font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;

BUT when I initially tried a search and replace function within the phpMyAdmin panel the system balked over the quoted 'Open Sans'.  I had a similar response when I entered a mysql command in the Run SQL query/queries window.

I have looked around the StackOverflow site and I saw some references to possibly using a \ in front of the quotes, but it didn't seem to actually apply in the situation I am trying to do a search and replace.

Any hints on what the mysql command needs to be in this type of situation..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't apply? It certainly does. Show what you tried. Another option is to use double quotes around the string.

Comment: I was trying to search and replace the 'Open Sans' - but in my attempt I only used the single quote around the fond family.  Thanks to Spencer I realized my mistake... I did not put quotes around the quotes ie ''Open Sans'' ( ie two single quotes in front and two single quotes after...

Comment: This is why we ask you to post your code, so we can see precisely what you did wrong and show how to correct it, rather than having to guess.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Write it as a SELECT statement first. We can use the MySQL `REPLACE` function. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

e.g.

```
SELECT t.mycol AS oldval
     , REPLACE(t.mycol,'font-family: Verdana;','font-family: ''Open Sans'', sans-serif;') AS newval 
--                                             ^             ^^         ^^             ^
  FROM mytable t 
 WHERE t.mycol LIKE '%font-family: Verdana;%'
```

Note that single quote characters in a string literal can be specified by two single quote characters.

As a demonstration, consider:

```
 SELECT 'It''s good' AS foo 
 --     ^  ^^      ^
```

Once we have a tested and verified expression for newval, we can use that expression in an `UPDATE` statement

```
UPDATE mytable t
   SET t.mycol = REPLACE(t.mycol,'font-family: Verdana;','font-family: ''Open Sans'', sans-serif;') 
 WHERE t.mycol LIKE '%font-family: Verdana;%'
```

Note that this will replace only the first occurrence of the string in `mycol`.  A subsequent execution will find the next occurrence of the search string, and replace that.

Also note that `REPLACE` performs a *case-sensitive* match.

Comment: It seems that the use of the ' before and after the quoted selection was the part I was missing.   Not sure where the regex \ enters in to the story... but the single quote in front and back of the quoted text worked.   Many thanks.

Comment: If this answered the question that was asked, consider marking the answer as accepted.  It's not really about adding single quote in front and back.  Within a SQL string literal (enclosed in single quotes), a literal single quote character can be *escaped* using another single quote character. That is, within a string literal, two consecutive single quote characters are interpreted as one literal single quote character. If we don't escape a single quote character, that would be interpreted as the end of the string literal.